# How do Captain Marvel's powers work in Endgame?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, captain-marvel

At the end of *Captain Marvel*, we find out that the reason Danvers's powers are so strong is that

> they are drawn directly from the Tesseract, AKA one of the Infinity Stones.

However, early on in *Avengers: Endgame*,

> Thanos destroys all of the Infinity Stones.

At first glance, it appears that this should have depowered Captain Marvel before she was ever even able to make it to the first fight scene she took part in.  Do we have any good explanation for why that didn't happen?

Comment: See [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/207599/98028) to a very very similar question on SFF.

Comment: Indeed, it's specifically stated in *Captain Marvel* that she absorbed the energy from the power source. Not that the stone *continues to provide power*. Carol actually says that the "blast" gave her the powers.

Comment: @Jenayah I saw that question.  I pointed out that it would be a massive plothole if Thanos wasn't able to trivially depower her in the (back then still unreleased) *Endgame,* and now that it's out, I don't see how anything has changed on that front.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I don't get it? The source being destroyed doesn't mean depowerment, as they don't need it anymore?

Comment: @Jenayah See my comment on the answer below.  That only makes sense if she's holding power from the Stone within her, rather than holding a link through which she draws power from the stone.  Of those two alternatives, having it be a link works well, while having it be a "battery," so to speak, is immensely problematic for multiple reasons.

Comment: @MasonWheeler the entire MCU is "immensely problematic for multiple reasons" but I strongly disagree that a link from the stone that she draws power through makes more sense. That makes less sense than her simply being give power by the stone in the blast.Peter Parker doesn't continue to draw his abilities from the spider that bit him.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: “I don't see how anything has changed on that front.” Your misunderstanding of how Captain Marvel's powers work certainly hasn't changed. You know how Spider-Man is still Spider-Man even though the spider's dead, Ned? Same deal with Captain Marvel and the Tesseract. Same deal with Scarlett Witch.

Answer (score 14):

Even though you have gained power from something, it doesn't always mean that you will lose it once it is destroyed. Captain Marvel acquired her powers from a warp drive (powered by Tessaract) which was destroyed, and she still had her powers.

There are many examples of this where there is no need of source lying around to make their powers work. For example, that radioactive spider from Spider-Man, or Shazam after he gave his powers to Billy.

Comment: I don't know. To me it seems clear that what she absorbed was not the drive's *charge* of "Stone Power," but rather *its link to the stone along which it was drawing power.* Otherwise, if she was just holding a finite amount of energy, you get three problems. First, it should always be apparent that she has that power inside of her, (glowing, etc) not just when she's tapping it. Second, without the power she's just an ordinary human, so containing the power should destroy her.  (See Quill in GotG for an analogous situation.) Third, she should have run out somewhere in the course of ~25 years.

Comment: @MasonWheeler *"so containing the power should destroy her."* however even in the flash back of that group using the Power Stone and that slave girl of Taneleer Tivan's they didn't die right away and Carol did have something suppressing her power for years. also keep in mind that those who were destroyed from the Power Stone held it without a container while the Space Stone was in it's container much like the Reality Stone with Malekith and Jane and the Power Stone with Ronan so one could suspect the power is lesser when in a container

Comment: @MasonWheeler it could be that the power doesn't work as a "limited" battery but that she constantly re-fuels. Photon chemistry inside her body or stuff, it's comics science after all :-)

Comment: In addition, Wanda (Scarlet Witch) and her brother (Quicksilver) were shown in an end credits scene of The Winter Soldier where their powers were received from Loki's staff, which contained the mind stone. As we saw, Wanda was also not affected by the destruction of the stones, though granted, she was absent from the timeline when the stones were destroyed.

Comment: Ehem...What about Asgard being the power source of both Thor and Hela?

Comment: @Memor-X Well, obviously you're wrong about all that because that's not what happens. What sort of answer are you expecting? The stone gave her permanent power

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir "Asgard is not a place, it's people."